# Updating the Quantity through SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I use the code found below to update a "Quantity" column in my table however I think because the Select and Update is inside of a foreach loop it is updating all of the products.

Furthermore, the products are also updated when the page is reloaded and the amount is increased based on how many times the user clicks on the add button. E.g. Click the add button twice the quantity increments by two each time.

I ideally need to be able to use the ItemID outside of the foreach loop but can't.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
foreach (UserItem ItemID in (List<UserItem>)Session["UserSession"])
{
    ConclusionPage.InsertCommand = "IF EXISTS (SELECT ItemID FROM tblUserItems WHERE UserID='@CurrentUser' AND ItemID='@ItemID')  UPDATE tblUserItems SET Quantity = Quantity+1 WHERE (UserID = '@CurrentUser') AND (ItemID = '@ItemID')";
    ConclusionPage.Insert();                 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable from a Foreach Loop ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369050/using-a-variable-from-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: When should the quantity be updated?

Comment: @Chuck The quantity should be updated say if the user goes to add an item but that item has already been added then the quantity should increment by one

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the IN() function in SQL.

This can take either a result set, or a comma delimited list.

```
UPDATE tblUserItems
SET Quantity = Quantity+1
WHERE UserID = @CurrentUser
AND ItemID IN(123,456,789,001)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the loop is actually independent on the `foreach`.  What I mean by this is that we are looping on `Session["UserSession"]`, but the SQL command does not do anything with the values in `Session["UserSession"]`.

All you should need to do is comment out the `foreach` line and the code should execute fine.

Somewhere above the code you have posted, there will be parameter variables (probably) named something like CurentUserCommand, ItemIdCommand (their types will be SqlCommand or DBCommand) - this are what the SQL statement is using.

Comment: The Foreach is inserting each ItemID into the table, that bits working fine it's just updating the quantity thats causing trouble

Comment: The ItemId variable in the foreach does not get used within the loop.  At the least the code doesn't make sense, and is redundant.

Comment: If I remove the foreach loop then the sql will only insert the last item in the session and the list not all of them